# jQuery UI Tabs not working with custom design

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui-tabs

I have simple three jQuery based tabs, I am not able to make it work with the custom css design.  i would appreciate if point to to the problem so that i can help fix it & make it work in a was that tabs switch without any animation or effect.

HTML Code: [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/svJtE/1/)

```
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   //For tabs
    $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });

    $('.tab_headers .tab_link_wrapper:nth-child(3n)').css('border-right', '0px');
    /*Since all the tabs are hidden with css we are displaying the tab with class .active_tab using fadeIn() 
    function. If you just want it to show with no effect, just put show() instead of fadeIn() */
    $('.active_tab').fadeIn();

    //when a tab link is clicked...  
    $('.tab_link').live('click', function (event) {

        /*...prevent the default behaviour...*/
        event.preventDefault();

        /* ...remove the tab_link_selected class from current active link... */
        $('.tab_link_selected').removeClass('tab_link_selected');

        /* ...and add it to the new active link */
        $(this).addClass('tab_link_selected');

        /*...get the title attribute (which corensponds to the id of the needed text container), 
        but you can use any attribute you want*/
        var container_id = $(this).attr('title');

        //...animate the current active_tab by changing it's height and opacity ...'  
        $('.active_tab').animate({

            height: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle'

            //...and when that animation ends...  
        }, function () {

            //...remove the active_tab class from the current active tab...  
            $(this).removeClass('active_tab');

            //...and add that class to the tab that corensponds the clicked link...  
            $(container_id).addClass('active_tab');

            //...and animate the new active_tab by using toggle on height and opacity again...  
            $('.active_tab').animate({

               // height: 'toggle', opacity: 'swing'
                height: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle'

            });
        });

</script>
<style type="text/css">
.tab_headers
{
    font-family: Helvetica, Georgia ,Tahoma, Arial,  sans-serif; 
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:#A78944;  
    min-height:25px;
    width:240px;
    overflow:hidden;
}  
.tab_link_wrapper
{
border-right:1px solid white;  
    float:left;
}
 .tab_link {  
float:left; /* important */  
/* just styling */  

background: #A78944;  
padding:5px 16px 4px 16px;  
margin-right:0px ;  
color:white;  
text-decoration:none; 

}  
.tab_link_selected{ background-color: #990044; } /* just a different tab link bg color when it's selected */  
.tab_text {  
display: none; /* hide the text containers */  
/* just styling */  
padding:0px;  
color:black; 
    font-family: Helvetica, Georgia ,Tahoma, Arial,  sans-serif; 
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:normal;

}  
.clear {clear: both;}  

.lblCounter
{
    padding-right:5px;
    color:#990044;
    font-family:  Georgia ,Helvetica,Tahoma, Arial,  sans-serif; 
    text-decoration:none;
}
.popular-article-title
{
    overflow:hidden;
    color:#000;
    line-height:26px;
     font-family:  Georgia ,Helvetica,Tahoma, Arial,  sans-serif; 
    text-align:justify;
    vertical-align:middle;
    float:left;
    min-height:26px;
    width:228px;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #EBEBEB;
     border-left:1px solid #EBEBEB;
      border-right:1px solid #EBEBEB;
     text-decoration:none;
}
.popular-links
{
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#tabs-popular-title
{
  width:240px;
  min-height:20px;
  padding:2px;
  text-align:left;
  color:#A78944;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
.most-popular-tabs-wrapper
{
    float:left;
    width:240px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
     overflow:hidden;
}
 </style>
 </head>
 </body>
 <div class="most-popular-tabs-wrapper">
<div id="tabs_wrapper">  
        <div class="tab_headers" id="tab_headers">
            <!--  the tab links  -->  
             <div class="tab_link_wrapper"><a title="#Articles" class="tab_link tab_link_selected" >Articles</a> </div> 
             <div class="tab_link_wrapper"><a title="#Writers" class="tab_link">Writers</a>  </div>
             <div class="tab_link_wrapper" style="border-right: 0px none;"><a title="#Videos" class="tab_link">Videos</a>  </div>
            <!--  end tab links  -->  
        </div>  
            <!--  clear it  -->  

            <!-- start tab text containers  -->  
        <div id="Articles" class="tab_text active_tab"  style="display: block;">  
            <div id="popular-article-wrapper">

                            <div class="popular-article-title">
                                 <span class="lblCounter" id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularArticles_lblCounter_0">1</span> 
                                 <a style="display:inline-block;border-width:0px;" href="article.aspx?PageID=5&amp;Language=en-US&amp;ParID=5&amp;Issue=5&amp;cid=16&amp;aid=17" class="popular-links" title="Belarus is open for business" id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularArticles_hylnkArticle_0"><span id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularArticles_lblArticleTitle_0">Article One title</span></a>
                              </div>

                            <div class="popular-article-title">
                                 <span class="lblCounter" id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularArticles_lblCounter_1">2</span> 
                                 <a style="display:inline-block;border-width:0px;" href="article.aspx?PageID=5&amp;Language=en-US&amp;ParID=5&amp;Issue=5&amp;cid=1&amp;aid=15" class="popular-links" title="Sheikh Mohammed holds fast to his father’s legacy" id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularArticles_hylnkArticle_1"><span id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularArticles_lblArticleTitle_1">Article One title two</span></a>
                              </div>

                            <div class="popular-article-title">
                                 <span class="lblCounter" id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularArticles_lblCounter_2">3</span> 
                                 <a style="display:inline-block;border-width:0px;" href="article.aspx?PageID=5&amp;Language=en-US&amp;ParID=5&amp;Issue=5&amp;cid=1&amp;aid=16" class="popular-links" title="It’s time the Lebanese removed their shackles" id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularArticles_hylnkArticle_2"><span id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularArticles_lblArticleTitle_2">Article three title</span></a>
                              </div>

                            <div class="popular-article-title">
                                 <span class="lblCounter" id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularArticles_lblCounter_3">4</span> 
                                 <a style="display:inline-block;border-width:0px;" href="article.aspx?PageID=5&amp;Language=en-US&amp;ParID=5&amp;Issue=5&amp;cid=17&amp;aid=23" class="popular-links" title="Building Dubai together" id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularArticles_hylnkArticle_3"><span id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularArticles_lblArticleTitle_3">Article four title </span></a>
                              </div>

                            <div class="popular-article-title">
                                 <span class="lblCounter" id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularArticles_lblCounter_4">5</span> 
                                 <a style="display:inline-block;border-width:0px;" href="article.aspx?PageID=5&amp;Language=en-US&amp;ParID=5&amp;Issue=5&amp;cid=2&amp;aid=43" class="popular-links" title="A day for reflection and appreciation" id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularArticles_hylnkArticle_4"><span id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularArticles_lblArticleTitle_4">Article five title</span></a>
                              </div>

                            <div class="popular-article-title">
                                 <span class="lblCounter" id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularArticles_lblCounter_5">6</span> 
                                 <a style="display:inline-block;border-width:0px;" href="article.aspx?PageID=5&amp;Language=en-US&amp;ParID=5&amp;Issue=5&amp;cid=6&amp;aid=18" class="popular-links" title="A Royal Visit" id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularArticles_hylnkArticle_5"><span id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularArticles_lblArticleTitle_5">Article seven title</span></a>
                              </div>

                            <div class="popular-article-title">
                                 <span class="lblCounter" id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularArticles_lblCounter_6">7</span> 
                                 <a style="display:inline-block;border-width:0px;" href="article.aspx?PageID=5&amp;Language=en-US&amp;ParID=5&amp;Issue=6&amp;cid=1&amp;aid=27" class="popular-links" title="The United Nations, just an expensive show" id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularArticles_hylnkArticle_6"><span id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularArticles_lblArticleTitle_6">Article One title</span></a>
                              </div>

                            <div class="popular-article-title">
                                 <span class="lblCounter" id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularArticles_lblCounter_7">8</span> 
                                 <a style="display:inline-block;border-width:0px;" href="article.aspx?PageID=5&amp;Language=en-US&amp;ParID=5&amp;Issue=6&amp;cid=1&amp;aid=26" class="popular-links" title="Sinister purpose behind anti-Islamic film" id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularArticles_hylnkArticle_7"><span id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularArticles_lblArticleTitle_7">Article One title</span></a>
                              </div>

                            <div class="popular-article-title">
                                 <span class="lblCounter" id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularArticles_lblCounter_8">9</span> 
                                 <a style="display:inline-block;border-width:0px;" href="article.aspx?PageID=5&amp;Language=en-US&amp;ParID=5&amp;Issue=5&amp;cid=18&amp;aid=25" class="popular-links" title="Autobiography Launch" id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularArticles_hylnkArticle_8"><span id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularArticles_lblArticleTitle_8">Article One title</span></a>
                              </div>

                            <div class="popular-article-title">
                                 <span class="lblCounter" id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularArticles_lblCounter_9">10</span> 
                                 <a style="display:inline-block;border-width:0px;" href="article.aspx?PageID=5&amp;Language=en-US&amp;ParID=5&amp;Issue=5&amp;cid=2&amp;aid=36" class="popular-links" title="Seismic shift " id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularArticles_hylnkArticle_9"><span id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularArticles_lblArticleTitle_9">Article One title</span></a>
                              </div>

            </div>
        </div>  
        <div id="Writers" class="tab_text"style="display: block;">  
            <div id="popular-writters-wrapper">

                            <div class="popular-article-title">
                                 <span class="lblCounter" id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularWriters_lblCounter_0">1</span> 
                                 <a style="display:inline-block;border-width:0px;" href="writer.aspx?PageID=17&amp;language=en-US&amp;issue=5&amp;ParID=1&amp;CID=0&amp;aid=-1&amp;wid=1" class="popular-links" title="Khalaf Ahmad Al Habtoor" id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularWriters_hylnkArticle_0"><span id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularWriters_lblArticleTitle_0">Writer One</span></a>
                              </div>

                            <div class="popular-article-title">
                                 <span class="lblCounter" id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularWriters_lblCounter_1">2</span> 
                                 <a style="display:inline-block;border-width:0px;" href="writer.aspx?PageID=17&amp;language=en-US&amp;issue=5&amp;ParID=1&amp;CID=0&amp;aid=-1&amp;wid=2" class="popular-links" title="Joanna Andrews" id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularWriters_hylnkArticle_1"><span id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularWriters_lblArticleTitle_1">Writer two</span></a>
                              </div>

                            <div class="popular-article-title">
                                 <span class="lblCounter" id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularWriters_lblCounter_2">3</span> 
                                 <a style="display:inline-block;border-width:0px;" href="writer.aspx?PageID=17&amp;language=en-US&amp;issue=5&amp;ParID=1&amp;CID=0&amp;aid=-1&amp;wid=3" class="popular-links" title="The Media Office" id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularWriters_hylnkArticle_2"><span id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularWriters_lblArticleTitle_2">The Media Office</span></a>
                              </div>

                            <div class="popular-article-title">
                                 <span class="lblCounter" id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularWriters_lblCounter_3">4</span> 
                                 <a style="display:inline-block;border-width:0px;" href="writer.aspx?PageID=17&amp;language=en-US&amp;issue=5&amp;ParID=1&amp;CID=0&amp;aid=-1&amp;wid=4" class="popular-links" title="Linda S. Heard" id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularWriters_hylnkArticle_3"><span id="MainContent_ucMostPopular_rptPopularWriters_lblArticleTitle_3">Writer four</span></a>
                              </div>

            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="tab_text" id="Videos">  
                Comming Soon
         </div>  
     </div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's great to post your code, but do we really need all of it? Perhaps shorten it to a really simple set of options, tabs and styles, and then it'll be easier to find a fix :)

Answer (score 3):

Your code would work with just minor touches.

First, you should remove `style="display: block;"` from the both ids `#Articles"` and `#Writers`. You have already done to display your content adding class of `active_tab` to the id of `#Articles`.

Lastly, you forgot to enclose your script with `});`.

[JSFiddle source](http://jsfiddle.net/agriboz/svJtE/5/) / [Result](http://jsfiddle.net/agriboz/svJtE/5/embedded/result/)